# Salesforce1 / Visualforce / JQM: pass merge field parameter between internal pages

Tags: visualforce, jquerymobile

JQuery Mobile / VF / Salesforce1 use case

Basic issue is how to efficiently pass values (in the VF / JQM use case) from within one `apex:repeat` to another `apex:repeat` that is not nested to the first repeat. Each `apex:repeat` is used to populate a JQM page

1. Custom controller with map instantiated as `forecastStatus => QtrForecast` for current quarter. `QtrForecast` is a custom type with two properties: list of OppoWrapper and total Forecast in corporate currency.
2. VF page with two stacked JQM pages (`main`, `oppoList`) where `main` displays a list of `forecastStatus` : `totalForecastValCurrentQtr` pairs (Example: Won : $5,000; Commit: $2,000)
3. If user clicks on a specific row on the `main` page (say, 'Commit'), JQM `main` page links to JQM `oppoList` page that displays a list of Opportunities that make up that `forecastStatus` value (e.g. all Oppos in 'Commit' status).

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" controller="UtilVFCustomController" sidebar="false" showheader="false" standardstylesheets="false">
<html> 
<head> 
   <title>Current Quarter Forecast</title> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, height=device-height, width=device-width" />
<apex:styleSheet value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"/>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="main">
  <div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="b">
      <apex:repeat value="{!fcstStatusToQtrFcstMap}" var="fcstStatus">  <!--  iterates over map keys -->
         <li>
            <a href="#oppoList?forecastStatus={!fcstStatus}">   <!--  reference internal page that displays oppoList for this forecast status -->
                <div class="ui-grid-a">
                    <div class="ui-block-a">
                        <apex:outputText value="{!fcstStatus}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ui-block-b" style="text-align: right;">
                        <apex:outputText value="${0,number,##,###,##0.00}" >
                            <apex:param value="{!fcstStatusToQtrFcstMap[fcstStatus].totalCorpCurrency}"/>
                        </apex:outputText>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- ui-grid of forecasts by status -->
             </a>
         </li>
      </apex:repeat>
    </ul>
  </div> <!-- /content -->
</div> <!-- /main page -->

<div data-role="page" id="oppoList">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="b">
            <apex:repeat value="{!fcstStatusToQtrFcstMap[???howToBindToMapKey???].oWList}" var="oW">
                <li>
                    <a href="javascript: sforce.one.navigateToSObject('{!oW.o.id}','detail');">
                        <h4>{!oW.o.account.name} / {!oW.o.name}</h4>                            
                        <p>Forecast status: <strong><apex:outputText value="{!oW.o.Forecast_Status__c}"/></strong>,
                        {!oW.o.currencyIsoCode}
                        <strong><apex:outputText value="{0,number, #,###,##0.00}" styleClass="number">
                            <apex:param value="{!oW.o.amount}"/>
                        </apex:outputText></strong>
                         </p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </apex:repeat>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `???howToBindToMapKey???` in `oppoList` page indicates where I'm stuck.

I thought of a few things but am not sure what is best to adhere to the 'Mobile First' / JQM gestalt:

1. Use `action:support onClick` and `action:param` on the main page's `apex:repeat` to pass the selected `fcstStatus` to the controller so it could be referenced by the JQM `oppoList` page - but I thought the point was to avoid server round trips?
2. Use one of the recipes here: http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/ or here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582781/how-to-pass-and-get-parameters-between-two-pages-in-jquery-mobile to pass javascript values from main page to `oppoList` page but I can't see how to reference the Javascript value in the `apex:repeat's value=` merge field within the `oppoList` page.
3. Use multiple internal pages for each `forecastStatus`: 'Won', 'Commit', 'Upside' and dynamically generate the `href` in the main page's `apex:repeat`; Each status-specific JQM page's `apex:repeat` would be hard-coded bound to their respective map key. Workable when map has only three elements but hardly good design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend option 1 with a single page application (stacked divs with a data-role of page), as JQM has already loaded the next page into the DOM but not displayed it, whereas the action function wants to re-send the page.  It works okay with a multi-page app, but does require a round trip and full page refresh each click, which can be taxing for a mobile device especially with a 3G connection.

If you go the JavaScript route, option 2, you can't interact with the apex:repeat tag on the second page, as these have already been rendered when the (physical) page was rendered to the device.

Option 3 will quickly turn into a large footprint especially if running on a phone, so you might find you need to break up into a multi-page application to avoid running out of memory on the browser.

I've found that the best way to build an interactive web application of this nature is to rewrite the logic client side in JavaScript and use something like JavaScript remoting to pull  back the additional information and render it in the page.  This avoids the heavyweight view state and full HTTP postbacks and is much faster.  It does, however, mean that you need to write a fair bit of JavaScript as you have to carry out all of the DOM manipulation yourself.  An added complexity is getting JQM to re-markup the changed elements - it will do this for some HTML elements but not others.

If you aren't comfortable with JavaScript I would go with a multi-page application and pass the id of the selected element on the URL to the second page - that way you avoid the viewstate overhead even though you have a server round trip.

I covered this in more detail in my Dreamforce session on Mobilizing your Visualforce Application using JQM and Knockout.js.  The session recording is available at:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qSKgko_W_PQ

and the sample application is on github at:

https://github.com/keirbowden/DFSurveys

Comment: This was an extremely helpful response. (1) When your tool is  a VF hammer, then I obviously was trying to fit all problems into a VF mindset.  (2) The shift I need to coerce my brain to is that of mobile dev where Javascript and its frameworks are in control and SFDC is merely acting as a data retriever/data DML'er. This is very different than a normal VF MVC pattern. (3) Yet in an SFDC1 environment you need some sort of VF page (at main nav menu or publisher action) so it is easy to drop into the classic VF mindset which is where I got confused. For this app, I'm going with option 3.